# Show certain InfoWindow in Google Map API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

I wrote the following code to display markers. There are 2 buttons which show Next or Previous Infowindow for markers. But problem is that InfoWindows are not shown using google.maps.event.trigger
Can someone help me with this problem. Thank you.
Here is code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Common Loader</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var infowindow;
  var map;
  var bounds;
  var markers = [];
  var markerIndex=0;

  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.051407, 28.991134);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

      markers = document.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("name"), latlng, markers[i].getAttribute("phone"), markers[i].getAttribute("distance"));
       }
    rebound(map);
  }

  function createMarker(name, latlng, phone, distance) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});

    var myHtml = "<table style='width:100%;'><tr><td><b>" + name + "</b></td></tr><tr><td>" + phone + "</td></tr><tr><td align='right'>" + distance + "</td></tr></table>";

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: myHtml});
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;
  }

  function rebound(mymap){
    bounds    = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))));
    }
    mymap.fitBounds(bounds);
  }

  function showNextInfo()
  {
    if(markerIndex<markers.length-1)
          markerIndex++;
    else
          markerIndex = 0 ;
    alert(markers[markerIndex].getAttribute('name'));
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerIndex],"click");
  }
  function showPrevInfo()
  {
    if(markerIndex>0)
          markerIndex--;
    else
          markerIndex = markers.length-1 ;
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerIndex],'click');
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px; height:300px"></div>
<markers>
<marker name='Name1' lat='41.051407' lng='28.991134' phone='+902121234561' distance=''/>
<marker name='Name2' lat='40.858746' lng='29.121666' phone='+902121234562' distance=''/>
<marker name='Name3' lat='41.014604' lng='28.972256' phone='+902121234562' distance=''/>
<marker name='Name4' lat='41.012386' lng='26.978350' phone='+902121234562' distance=''/>
</markers>
<input type="button" onclick="showPrevInfo()" value="prev">&nbsp;<input type="button" onclick="showNextInfo()" value="next">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 20):

this is how i'm doing it

hope it can help ;)

```
 /**
  * map
  */
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.980278, 4.049835);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false
  }
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), myOptions);

 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 var markerArray = [];

 function makeMarker(options){
   var pushPin = new google.maps.Marker({map:map});
   pushPin.setOptions(options);
   google.maps.event.addListener(pushPin, 'click', function(){
     infoWindow.setOptions(options);
     infoWindow.open(map, pushPin);
   });
   markerArray.push(pushPin);
   return pushPin;
 }

 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(){
   infoWindow.close();
 });

 function openMarker(i){
   google.maps.event.trigger(markerArray[i],'click');
 };

 /**
 *markers
 */
 makeMarker({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.943962, 3.891220),
   title: 'Title',
   content: '<div><h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<div>'
 });

openMarker(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't work because it is triggering `click` event on `markers[markerIndex]` which is not map marker but information about DOM element with tag `marker`.

To get it running you have to add global array which will contain list of map markers:

```
var markerList = [];
```

Change `initialize()` function to push map marker to that list in for loop:

```
markerList.push(marker);
```

Change functions `showNextInfo()` and `showPrevInfo()` to trigger event on map marker:

```
//google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerIndex], "click");
google.maps.event.trigger(markerList[markerIndex], "click");
```